# How can I use AppCompatEditText with Saripaar validation library

Tags: android-appcompat, saripaar

So currently it shows the error icon on the AppCompatEditText with invalid entry on validation but when I click on that view it throws an exception.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
```

Comment: I don't see how this is related to Saripaar. Also `AppCompat*` widgets are meant to be used only if you are writing custom views. They are automatically used when you use `EditText` in your layouts.